# How do I automatically "nice" particular users' jobs?

Tags: nice

If I have server users who often forget to use the 'nice' command for their jobs on a web server, is it possible to change a setting so that the default priority for everything they launch is slightly higher than zero?

Comment: How do these users start the processes that should be "niced"?

Comment: Just on the command line, forgetting to nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in `/etc/security/limits.conf` file.

Assuming your users are member of a group `users`, you can add a line like this:

```
@users soft nice 5
```

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like `nice` and nice-ness isn't the tool you actually want – cgroups would be! (And relying on users to `nice` themselves is an architectural mistake ;) as you notice in practice!)

You can give users, services and generally "slices" a quota on things in Linux – pretty much like nice-ness can be used to de-priotize some processes when CPU contention is high, but at a much wider scope – also applying to I/O bandwidth, RAM, number of processes, and a few other things.

It's fairly simple: Say you want to restrict the user with uid 1234 (who is currently logged in, so that their slice exists) to get ¼ of the CPU time of the nginx HTTP service:

```bash
systemctl set-property user-1234.slice CPUShares=500 MemoryHigh=16G
systemctl set-property nginx.service CPUShares=2000 MemoryHigh=28G
```

(these changes are permanent)

If you want to restrict *all logged in users in sum*, use `user.slice`.

If you want to restrict specific users a priori, make a /lib/systemd/system/user-1234.slice

```ini
[Unit]
Description=Goddammit stop hogging my server, Carl
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Before=slices.target
CPUShares=500
MemoryHigh=2G

[Slice]
Slice=user-slice

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I have server users who often forget to use the 'nice' command for their jobs on a web server

It sounds like you are doing it wrong / that this is the XY problem. Why do technically naive "users" have shell access to host in a server role? Why are you allowing other processes to run on this box? Why do these processes need more CPU time than the OS wants to give them?